Unsupported("cannot serialize enum newtype variant `Example::Data`")
I am writing a XML parser and generator using quick-xml crate.
Any enum variant on the top level and unit enums inside a struct work fine. But when trying to serialize a nested struct or newtype variant I'm getting the error below:
<Val/>
Val
Val

<Data>99</Data>
Data(99)
Data(99)


<Test><num>100</num><st>Please work...</st><o>Val</o></Test>
Test { num: 100, st: "Please work...", o: Val }
Test { num: 100, st: "Please work...", o: Val }

thread 'main' panicked at lib/src/main.rs:98:28:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Unsupported("cannot serialize enum newtype variant `Example::Data`")
stack backtrace:

This is my code:
use serde::{
    ser::{SerializeStruct, SerializeStructVariant, SerializeTupleVariant, Serializer},
    Deserialize, Serialize,
};

use quick_xml::{de::from_str, se::to_string};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Test {
    num: u8,
    st: String,
    o: Example,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Example {
    Val,
    Data(u8),
}

fn main() {
    // works fine
    let x = Example::Val;

    let sr = to_string(&x).unwrap();
    let ds: Example = from_str(&sr).unwrap();

    println!("{}", sr);

    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}\n", ds);

    // works fine
    let x = Example::Data(99);

    let sr = to_string(&x).unwrap();
    let ds: Example = from_str(&sr).unwrap();

    println!("{}", sr);

    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}\n\n", ds);

    // works fine

    let y = Test {
        num: 100,
        st: "Please work...".to_owned(),
        o: Example::Val,
    };

    let sr = to_string(&y).unwrap();
    let ds: Test = from_str(&sr).unwrap();

    println!("{}", sr);

    println!("{:?}", y);
    println!("{:?}\n", ds);

    // doesn't work

    let y = Test {
        num: 100,
        st: "Please work...".to_owned(),
        o: Example::Data(99),
    };

    let sr = to_string(&y).unwrap();
    let ds: Test = from_str(&sr).unwrap();

    println!("{}", sr);

    println!("{:?}", y);
    println!("{:?}", ds);
}

I also tried implementing Serialize by hand, but it resulted in the same error.

That's an open issue #717.
For now only unit variants can be used in a struct field that is not the $value. As documented:




Kind
Top-level and in $value field
In normal field
In $text field




Unit
<Unit/>
<field>Unit</field>
Unit


Newtype
<Newtype>42</Newtype>
Err(Unsupported)
Err(Unsupported)


Tuple
<Tuple>42</Tuple><Tuple>answer</Tuple>
Err(Unsupported)
Err(Unsupported)


Struct
<Struct><q>42</q><a>answer</a></Struct>
Err(Unsupported)
Err(Unsupported)




You can almost1 achieve the desired result with an intermediate struct:
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Test {
    num: u8,
    st: String,
    o: O,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct O {
    #[serde(rename = "$value")]
    value: Example,
}


1) It serializes Example::Val as <Val/> instead of Val
